# PXSelector only select one Filed

Tags: c#, acumatica

```
  #region EquimentID
  public abstract class quimentID : PX.Data.IBqlField { }
  protected Int32? _EquimentID;
  [PXInt]
  [PXSelector(
       typeof(EPEquipment.equipmentID),
       SubstituteKey = typeof(EPEquipment.equipmentCD),
       DescriptionField = typeof(EPEquipment.description)
    )]
  [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Equiment ID")]
  public virtual Int32? EquimentID { get; set; }
  #endregion
```

but i have a message "*Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'JOIN'.*" 
What is my error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace your `PXSelector` attribute with the following one:

```
[PXSelector(typeof(Search<EPEquipment.equipmentID>),
       SubstituteKey = typeof(EPEquipment.equipmentCD),
       DescriptionField = typeof(EPEquipment.description))]
```